# Can I safely remove stringer in garage?

Tags: wood, garage, support

There are two 2"x12"x8' stringers attached to studs in the garage with 1/2"x2-1/2" lag screws in order to mount a squat rack.

Is there any concern that I could compromise the integrity of the garage by removing removing the stringers?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you like your answer, please click the "check" icon to mark it as the right one. And you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: thanks @DanielGriscom, just waiting for someone to respond to my comment on the answer -- then I intend to accept

Answer (score 5):

Unless there is more to this than you've shown, this was added AFTER construction to permit the installation of the squat rack.  As such, it's NOT a part of the garage's structure and so removing it will not compromise it in any way.

Comment: thank you for the quick response! just want to make sure as I won't be leaving the 
 structure the same as initial construction: the holes left by removing the inch or so of lag screws won't affect strength of the studs?

Comment: Best answer vote and close topic ,No need for any more.